# Error when click on edit text android

Tags: java, android, android-logcat, android-studio-3.1

After actualization android studio to version 3.1 I have problem with my project.
When i click on edit text activity closing and throw exception.
I have no idea why is this happening, pls help.

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4180)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:144)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: share your code and logcat

Comment: project is big but i can say that i am nothing do with edit text. it is just defined in xml

Comment: show only edit text part

Comment: `<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etGlassSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Wielkość kieliszka" />`

Comment: In activity i am not using it but it is crashing when click it

Comment: if you are not using this then you can comment this

Comment: i mean i used this before but i comented this because of this error. now it is only in xml.

Comment: comment in xml also

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in new android studio version(3.1), hope they fix it ASAP.
If you run same app without changing anything in previous version like 3.0 this app will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For now disabling it (Edit configuration settings -> Profiling -> Enable advanced profiling) prevents EditText from crashing